# What can we learn from when the trading volume is much higher/lower than average?

Tags: stocks, trading-volume

This one is less than 50% of its avg. value.

[image: 0700@HK]

This one is more than 3 times of its avg. value.

[image: YHOO@Nasdaq]

Are there any indications from this information?

Thanks,

Comment: Check the news at the first intance. Never go by volume. First news and then volume(price)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not look at volume in isolation but look at it together with other indicators and/or the release of news (good or bad).

When there is lower than average volume this could be an indication that the stock is in a bit of a holding pattern, possibly waiting for some company or economic news to come out (especially when accompanied by small changes in price). It could also mean that trading in a certain direction is drying up and the trend is about to end (this could be accompanied with a large move in price).

When there is higher than average volume (2 to 3 times more or higher), this could be due to the release of company results, company or economic news, or the start or end of a trend (especially if accompanied by a gap). A large increase in volume accompanied by a large fall in price (usually a gap down) may also be an indication the stock has gone ex-dividend.

There could be a range of reasons for variations in volume to the average volume. That is why you need to look at other indicators, company reporting and news, and economic news in combination with the volume changes to get a grasp of what is really happening.